# mod_rewrites in nested .htaccess causing strange 404

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have an apache HTTP server with a directory structure as such:

```
/
---- api/
---- ---- index.php
---- ---- .htaccess
---- index.php
---- .htaccess
```

**/.htaccess**:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/
```

**/api/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
```

My objective was to display the `index.php` of a directory when it was called without a trailing backslash. However, calling `http://example.com/api` results in a 404. Commmenting out the one line in `/api/.htaccess` causes everything to work as expected.

I'm having a hard time understanding this behavior as the [doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine) for `RewriteEngine On` says nothing about it. Could someone shed some light on mod_rewrite's workings here?

The directory, zipped up: [mega.nz](https://mega.nz/#!QF4EkZDT!4i2OI2E0bfg07bHnxS6rFCAxuGFitEsz2l20BrHYwxs)

Comment: Why do you set `DirectorySlash off`?

Comment: Since I don't want Apache to send a 301 when a request to a directory doesn't end in a slash.

Answer (score 1):

> Commmenting out the one line in /api/.htaccess causes everything to work as expected.

Yes, because in a per-directory context, mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default (which differs to other modules). By enabling the mod_rewrite engine in a subdirectory you are *overriding* the mod_rewrite directives in the parent directory - and these directives in the parent directory are required to make your `http://example.com/api` request work as expected.

Note that the `DirectorySlash` directive is part of mod_dir, so this is not overridden. So `DirectorySlash` is still `Off`. This then results in Apache attempting to serve the *directory* `/api`, which fails. (Although I would have expected this to have resulted in a 403, rather than a 404?)

The mod_rewrite directives in the .htaccess file in the document root apply to *all* subdirectories by default, so there is no need to do anything special here.

If you want to *inherit* mod_rewrite directives from the parent `.htaccess` file then you need to look at the [`RewriteOptions` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions) - but per-directory inheritance with mod_rewrite has additional caveats.

> Since I don't want Apache to send a 301 when a request to a directory doesn't end in a slash.

Ah OK. (Those directives are otherwise rather "unusual"!) However, that 301 redirect is intended to "fix" the request. By internally rewriting the request you now have a potential duplicate content issue.

Comment: I tried changing the contents of */api/.htaccess* to ```RewriteEngine On\nRewriteRule ^ index.php```, in the intention that now a file called ```/api/index.php``` would exist. But it still 404s?

Comment: That `RewriteRule` directive never gets processed, because the resulting request is not actually mapped to that subdirectory - at least not in so far as the rewriting phase of mod_rewrite (the trailing slash is required). The `RewriteEngine` directive would seem to be processed during an earlier phase (the `RewriteEngine` directive can appear _anywhere_ in the .htaccess file). Can you just confirm that this is resulting in a 404 and not a 403?

Comment: I'm 100%. Also the entire situation is fairly simple to replicate (Around 4 files, 5 lines of code). Let me know if you want me to zip it up or so.

Comment: I would be interested to see the actual source. An error is expected (as mentioned), although I would have expected to see a 403, rather than a 404. What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: I've tried your code on two different servers (Apache 2.4.7 Windows and Apache 2.2.31 Linux) and I get the default Apache 403 when accessing `example.com/api` (no trailing slash) on both (no 404) - as expected. This is with directory indexes disabled (which is, incidentally, where the 403 comes from). Are you seeing the _default_ Apache 404 document? I can only think there is perhaps something overriding the 403 in the server config?? Custom error document perhaps?

Comment: I'm on Windows' WampServer. The error document is the default one, "Not Found\nThe requested URL /api was not found on this server.". Chrome devtools shows the status code as a 404 as well.